# What are the best books to study generative syntax?

Tags: syntax, reference-request

I'm looking for a good book to study generative syntax from an introductory level to intermediate or advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Liliane Haegeman's 'introduction to government and binding theory'. This book is very useful at introductory levels, and she explains factual issues in language and linguistics in a very simplified manner. If you want another simpler introductory book try Andrew Carnie's 'syntax'. But I advise you to read the first. It will build your critical linguistic thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Radford's "[Transformational Grammar, A First Course](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/transformational-grammar/47A6B24E28CED7D6684CE2EBAFFDFFF7)" and Liliane Haegeman's "[Introduction to Government and Binding Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0631190678)" would be sufficient for numerous purposes. I can also recommend Gert Webelhuth's "[Government and Binding Theory and The Minimalist Program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0631180613)", and Andrew Carnie's "[Syntax: A Generative Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470655313)"

In addition, one should read Chomsky's major books on these topics. It is a must and very enlightening.

Comment: I recommend Andrew Carnie's. It's the best introduction to syntax textbook.